# how to disable keyring prompt when you don't know the current /old password

Tags: 14.04, keyrings

I am trying to disable the keyring prompt on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS laptop. I'm trying to add a new wifi hotspot and it keeps prompting me for the keyring password.

I've read various posts here about how to do it including: 
1.  remove it as a start up application
2.  go into "passwords and keys" and try to change the login settings.

The problem with the first option is that when I go into start up applications, I only have one item called: "Indicator Application".  I don't see anything else there that I can disable.

When I go into passwords and keys, in order to reset the password, you need to know the old / current keyring password, which I don't know. I don't ever recall setting up a keyring password.  I think I need to do more reading on what it is and how it's set up... which i'm in the process of doing.  But I thought I'd also post a question.

I have one account set up on this machine, and a boot password.
I tried both of them to unlock the key ring, but neither worked.

Any suggestions would be appreciated - even if it's just pointing me to the right article to read.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't know old keyring it is the first password ever used with linux

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delete the keyrings

```
rm ~/.local/share/keyrings -fr
```

The next time it is needed a new one will be generated and you will be prompted for a new password. You will loose all the information that was stored in the old keyring.